# how to migrate from git-svn to gitolite and retain history

Tags: git, git-svn, gitolite

We have been using SVN and slowly the developers have been migrating to git-svn.  Now we're ready to make the plunge and completely move to git (using gitolite).  I am not sure how to migrate our repository into gitolite and maintain history.  I don't know if I should try to convert the svn repo directly or use my local git-svn copy and push that.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use [SubGit](http://subgit.com) to translate your Subversion repositories to Git.
The following single command should be enough to perform translation:

```
$ subgit install svn_repos
```

After that you'll get Git repository in `svn_repos/.git` or multiple Git repositories in `svn_repos/git/` (in case you keep multiple projects in svn_repos).

You may then continue to use SubGit to keep both Subversion and Git access or just uninstall it and use svn_repos as a Git repository only:

```
$ subgit uninstall svn_repos
```

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of SubGit.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - I hadn't heard of the project.  How would I then take that git repo and push it to the gitolite (I'm new to remote git repos - I've been using svn as the repo all the time.)

Comment: @Yehosef SubGit is a new project, so no wonder you hand't yet heard of it.

Comment: As for pushing: after `subgit install svn_repos` completes translation, `svn_repos` _becomes_ a normal Git repository. So just run `git --git-dir=svn_repos/.git push --all gitolite_repos_url`.

Comment: This way, however, you'll loose Git/Subversion mirroring feature of SubGit; to keep it you'll need to move translated Git repository as it is to Gitolite (or specify its path in gitolite configuration). I'll check how to do that.

Comment: It sounds like subgit is just a way to get svn into git.  I already have a git copy of svn from using git-svn - so I could just the `git --git-dir=svn_repos/.git push --all gitolite_repos_url` on that to push the history to the remote?    Or because the .git from git-svn will be functionally different from the .git from subgit?  thanks!

Comment: git-svn and Subgit translation result may differ, but in general Git repository produced by SubGit and that produced by git-svn has no functional differences.

Comment: update - the command worked to push the git-svn repo to gitserver - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up I've made a short HOWTO blog post on migrating from Svn to Gitolite: see http://blog.subgit.com/from-svn-to-gitolite/